# How to use shutil.copytree in case of whitespaces in a filename

Tags: python, copy, whitespace, shutil, copytree

I can't use `shutil.copytree()` when there are whitespaces in the filename.
I think I have to use the raw string --> `r'your-string'`
But how to implement this?

EDIT: This is my code.

```
import os
import shutil
import sys

usb_folder = os.listdir("/media/kame")

# create path       okay
path_ = r'/media/kame/' + str(usb_folder)[2:-2]

# copy files
path_2 = path_ + '/main'

#try:
#    os.makedirs(path_2)
#except:
#    pass

shutil.copytree('/home/kame/Desktop/main/bilder/geschichte',path_2)
```

And this is the Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
    shutil.Error: [('/home/kame/Desktop/main/bilder/geschichte/Screenshot from 2014-12-24 11:09:06.png', '/media/kame/INTENSO/main/Screenshot from 2014-12-24 11:09:06.png', "[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: '/media/kame/INTENSO/main/Screenshot from 2014-12-24 11:09:06.png'"), ('/home/kame/Desktop/main/bilder/geschichte/Screenshot from 2014-12-22 21:41:28.png'
```

Comment: `shutil.copytree` should work with whitespace, and this has nothing to do with raw strings.

Comment: I want to make an automatic backup from my PC to an USB-stick. I can copy all my files without this, which contains whitespaces. :(

Comment: Can you provide an example where and how this fails?

Comment: It works with `shutil.copy()`, but I can't use this for copying folders. One Moment.

Answer (score -1):

It works with:

```
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree('/home/kame/Desktop/main', path_2)
```

But why `shutil.copytree()` doesn't work?